# Regex - Use /* in JS without getting my code in comment

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to do some split, like this:

```
$(element).split(/*(.+)?/)[1]);
```

But those `/*` characters, make my code be as a comment.
How can I use it & avoid from this to happen ?

Comment: That would be no valid regex anyway. Do you want to match an asterisk?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, It is really invalid, and yes, I want to match an asterisk.

Comment: As [`*` has a special meaning](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), you'd need to escape it with a backslash. Btw, the sequence `/*` can be valid inside a regex without creating a comment (the reason for a very complicated comment syntax specification :-), for example in `/^\/*$/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape the `*` character to match it literally. It means something within a regex. It means the previous token is matched 0 or more times.

```
/\*
```

The regex should be:

```
/\*(.+)?/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add an expression to the start that doesn't make a difference:

```
/.{0,}*(.+)?/
```